# How to relate nodes in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Whats the best way to relate content in drupal 7 ?

I have three content Types

- Product Group ( With detail page )
- Product ( With detail page )
- Application ( With detail page )

A product belongs to a product group.

An application belongs to a product group.

How can i do this kind of relathionship in the best way?

Answer (score 1):

The [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) Module is used for **complex relationship**.

The [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) is what you need if you want **simple relashionships**.

You can read the answers to this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13862/relation-vs-references-vs-entity-reference-for-managing-node-reference-type-re) to see the options.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the most effective way to achieve this is by using [entity reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).
You can add fields in your content types that their values are references to other content types.
For example you can add a field "Product group" in your product content type that can be populated by the values/nodes of you Product Group content type.

Comment: Is it possible to make a view of all products belonging to the product group i am currently viewing?

Comment: And can i use this view in a panel ?

Comment: I haven't use panels so I cannot answer this. What I do is using the nid of the product group,when viewing product group page, as a contextual filter in a view of products.